# Initialize pointer to a struct with a compound literal

Tags: c, pointers, compound-literals

I'm new to C and I'm trying to understand the syntax for compound literals. My question is similar to [Initializing a pointer to compound literals in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557537/initializing-a-pointer-to-compound-literals-in-c) but I don't think that answers it. If have a struct and a type defined as a pointer to the struct like this:

```
typedef struct thing *thing_t;
struct thing
{
    int id;
    char *name;
};
```

Then I can create a `thing_t` like this:

```
thing_t instance = & (struct thing) {
    .id = 1,
    .name = "A"
};
```

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize a `thing_t` without explicitly referring to `struct thing`, e.g. I tried this to see if it was valid syntax:

```
thing_t instance = (* thing_t) {
    .id = 1,
    .name = "A"
};
```

but the compiler errors.  The compiler must "know" that the `thing_t` type holds a pointer to a `thing`, but is there syntax that allows to use the two interchangably in this context?

(I don't have a particular use case for this, I'm just trying to understand how the type and the struct are related).

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind typedefs. `typedef struct thing thing_t;` - problem solved.

Comment: Try `->` instead of `.`, that may work

Comment: You might want to be careful with lifetime when using pointers to compound literals when you're new to C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to initialize a `thing_t` without
>   explicitly referring to `struct thing`, e.g. I tried this to see if it
>   was valid syntax:
>
> ```
> thing_t instance = (* thing_t) {
>     .id = 1,
>     .name = "A"
> };
> ```
>
> but the compiler errors. The compiler must "know" that the thing_t
>   type holds a pointer to a thing,

Yes, it does, though it is poor form to define a type alias that hides pointer nature, as you have done, and it is *especially* poor form to do so with a name that does not somehow provide a clue about that.

> but is there syntax that allows to
>   use the two interchangably in this context?

The syntax for a compound literal includes the parenthesized type specifier.  That's not a cast, it's part of the literal itself.  You cannot do without it.  If you want to avoid saying `struct`, though, then you can kill two birds with one stone by changing your type alias so that it describes the struct type itself, not a pointer to one:

```
typedef struct thing thing_t;
struct thing {
    int id;
    char *name;
};
thing_t *instance = & (thing_t) {
    .id = 1,
    .name = "A"
};
```

Not only does it work, but it's a heck of a lot clearer than your proposal.  For example, the use of the `&` operator matches up with the clear declaration of variable `instance` as a pointer.

Comment: Nice.  I've been away from C for some time, and am learning C99 features more or less "by accretion."  Thanks for the example of struct literal syntax and by-name member initialization.  Both are nice additions to the C89/90 language.

Comment: This may be intended for file scope, but I do not see that explicitly stated in the question or this answer. Inside a function, a compound literal has automatic storage duration associated with its enclosing block, so its address should be used with caution.

Comment: That's a useful observation, @Eric.  Indeed, the question does not touch on the lifetimes of the objects represented by compound literals, and I have answered only what was asked, but object lifetime is an important consideration for how a pointer such as the OP is obtaining may be used.

Comment: I'm just writing toy programs while I read through a book so it didn't matter in this case.  Useful to know though, I hadn't thought about why it needed to be different from string literals.
Thanks @JohnBollinger for your answer!